# create side panels in bokeh for displaying details of hovered data point

Tags: widget, visualization, bokeh

I have seen great examples of how bokeh allows you to hover over a data point and display pop up details for it. There are cases the details is so overwhelming voluminous, it really requires a side panel to display it all. Is bokeh a complete enough widget toolkit where I can create a side panel to the main display and show details of a data point following the cursor?

Can someone point out some sample code, or at least the relevant api's.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many examples on https://docs.bokeh.org . What you want is possible by adding a callback and updating the relevant part. In this example the div is what you name a side panel in your question.

```
#for bokeh 1.0.4
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,Div,Row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.events import Tap

#the data
d={'x':[1,2],'y':[3,4],'info':['some information on a first datapoint','some information on a second datapoint']}

source=ColumnDataSource(d)
tooltips = [("x", "$x"),("y", "$y"),("info","@info")]
fig=figure(tools="tap,reset",tooltips=tooltips)
c=fig.circle('x','y',source=source,size=15)

def callback(event):
    indexActive=source.selected.indices[0]
    layout.children[1]=Div(text=d['info'][indexActive])#adjust the info on the right

fig.on_event(Tap, callback)

div=Div(text=d['info'][0])

layout=Row(fig,div)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

To run this code, save it as code.py, open a cmd and type "bokeh serve code.py --show".

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a higher-level API for building and linking Bokeh-based plots, you can use HoloViews; see linking examples at http://holoviews.org/reference/index.html#streams and instructions at http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Custom_Interactivity.html .  For example:

```
import param, numpy as np, holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, streams
hv.extension('bokeh')

xvals = np.linspace(0,4,202)
ys,xs = np.meshgrid(xvals, -xvals[::-1])
img = hv.Image(np.sin(((ys)**3)*xs))

pointer = streams.PointerXY(x=0,y=0, source=img)
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(lambda x, y: hv.Points([(x, y)]), streams=[pointer])
dmap = dmap.redim.range(x=(-0.5,0.5), y=(-0.5,0.5))

img + dmap.opts(size=10)
```

[image: sample]